# Function with formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I am quite new when it comes to Google Sheets, but I just created a function which gets me the Amazon stock price, see below:

```
var temp = '=INDEX(GoogleFinance("AMZN", "CLOSE", DATEVALUE(A5)),2,2)';
```

It works but the problem is, that I want to be flexible when it comes to the date (DATEVALUE). Currently, I have a date in my cell A5, but I actually have a IF statement, which uses the variable `i`. So, preferably it should at the end look like `Ai` whereas of course `i` can be 7 or 15 or whatever number.

How can I achieve that?

I already tried `A + i` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var temp = '=INDEX(GoogleFinance("AMZN", "CLOSE", DATEVALUE(A'+ i +')),2,2)';
```